# How to get client IP address in Kubernetes with service type ClusterIP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have services with ClusterIP in Kubernetes and using `nginx` (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) to expose these services to the internet. When I try to get client IP address in application I am getting cluster's node IP. How can I retrieve actual client IP?

I looked into `"externalTrafficPolicy": "Local"` settings in service but for that service type must be `LoadBalancer`.

I also tried update ingress annotations with:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Forwarded-For,csrf-token"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com"
```

But, still, it's not working. Please advice!

Comment: Packets sent to service type `ClusterIP` from within the cluster are never source NAT’d if you’re running kube-proxy in `iptables` mode per https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip. Is kube-proxy running in `iptables` mode on all the nodes? Check output of `curl localhost:10249/proxyMode` on all the nodes.

Comment: @VikramHosakote: I don't know what kube-proxy is. Never setup before.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible today. Please see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67202 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69811 for more discussion around this.

If you want to get the client IP address, you'll need to use `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` types.

Comment: Is there no option with ClusterIP? because I'm using the traefik-ingress controller for managing routing. @Nikhita Raghunath